# Java word in string manipulation

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Java and I was wondering how to switch words in a string. In my program, the user enters text into a string and its saved. The program should move the first word to the end of the string. Ex. "I love cats and hate dogs" should be changed to "love cats and hate dogs I."

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter at least one thing you love and one thing you hate using the words hate and love: ");
String loveHate = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: You could split the string around a space delimiter and then pop the first element in the array onto the end.

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) should get you started...

An example...

```
int spaceIndex = loveHate.indexOf(" "); //index of a first space character
String first = loveHate.substring(0, spaceIndex);
String rest = loveHate.substring(spaceIndex + 1); 

String reversed = rest + " " + first;
```

Comment: +1 For this simple case, regex are overkill and less efficient than two substring calls.

Comment: I believe the rest should be: `loveHate.substring(spaceIndex + 1);` since I don't think he wants the space that was between the first and second words.

Answer (score 2):

You could swap the first word to the end with this regular expression:

```
loveHate.replaceAll("(\\w+)(.*)", "$2 $1");
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
This was my original response, but in hindsight @iccthedral's answer is probably the best.

One approach would be to split the text into words, then just concatenate the first word to the end of everything that came after it.

```
String input = "I love cats and hate dogs";
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
String firstWord = words[0];
StringBuilder everythingAfterFirstWord = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 1 ; i < words.length ; i++){
   String word = words[i];
   everythingAfterFirstWord.append(word);
   everythingAfterFirstWord.append(" ");
}
String switched = everythingAfterFirstWord + firstWord;
```

Another approach would be to use regular expressions. Match the first word, and everything else then use String.replaceAll to switch the two groups.

```
String switched = input.replaceAll("^(\\w+)\\s(.*)$", "$2 $1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String ss = "i love you";
        String sss="";
        String temp="";
        String[] ssArr = ss.split("\\s");
        for(int i=0; i<ssArr.length; i++) {
            if(i==0) {
                temp = ssArr[i];
            }

            else {
                sss+=ssArr[i]+" ";
            }
             if(i==ssArr.length-1) {
                    sss+=temp;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(sss);
```

output: love you i